# Show that $f\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=\min\{1,1/|x|\}$. Show that $f\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I think I want $||f||_1$ to not be finite and $||f||_2<\infty$, but I'm confused as to how to compute those from a minimum function.  Would I just take $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ and compute as normal?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to have your function written in piecewise form, like $f(x)=\begin{cases} f_1(x) & x \in A_1 \\ f_2(x) & x \in A_2 \end{cases}$ and so on, because then $\| f \|_1 = \int_{A_1} |f_1| + \int_{A_2} |f_2| + \dots$ and similar for $\| f \|_2$. Can you do that for your function? Hint: there will be three pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f(x)=\min\{1,1/|x|\}$.

We may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx&=\int_{|x|\leq 1}|f(x)|dx+\int_{|x|> 1}|f(x)|dx\\\\
&=\int_{|x|\leq 1}1\:dx+\int_{|x|> 1}\frac1{|x|}dx\\\\
\end{align}
$$ and the latter integral is **divergent**, thus $f\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Similarly$$
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|^2dx&=\int_{|x|\leq 1}|f(x)|^2dx+\int_{|x|> 1}|f(x)|^2dx\\\\
&=\int_{|x|\leq 1}1\:dx+\int_{|x|> 1}\frac1{|x|^2}dx\\\\
\end{align}
$$ and both integrals are **convergent**, thus $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.